# print out all different items in a list and tell how often they occur python

Tags: python

I have a huge list of numbers and ranges. I want my program to browse through all of them and filter how often each item occurs. then it should print out the `Categories`and tell how often each category occurs.

I saw some ways to solve that problem but they all approach by asking for a specific number or item in their list. Then the program is able to tell how often that model is in the list.

```
list_of_cars = [["honda","blue"],["nissan","yellow"],["honda","blue"],["bmw","grey"]]
sorted(list_of_cars)
```

Now that I sorted the list I want to print a result in which each car and color is counted and the printed version should tell me how often every different car model is in the list.

The output should look like this:

```
print(sorted_list_of_cars) 

[["honda","blue" 2],["nissan","yellow"  1],["bmw,grey" 1]]
```

Comment: How the categories given? Could you also provide an example of what you want to achieve

Comment: It's not clear exactly how you want the output to look. Can you give an example of what the output should look like? Like would (honda, blue) and (honda, yellow) both go in the honda category or would each go in a different category because they are different colors?

Comment: @ Rashid 'Lee' Ibrahim. I added a possible output to my question. Actually honda blue and honde yellow wouldnt be in the same category. The program should only count items that are exactly the same. So just count blue hondas. Or only count yellow hondas if they occur twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to convert the members of the list into tuples (hashable type) and then use python Counter (tested on python 3.8.1):

```
from collections import Counter


list_of_cars = [["honda","blue"],["nissan","yellow"],["honda","blue"],["bmw","grey"]]
list_of_tuples = [tuple(item) for item in list_of_cars]
counter = Counter(list_of_tuples)
print(counter)
```

The output will be `Counter({('honda', 'blue'): 2, ('nissan', 'yellow'): 1, ('bmw', 'grey'): 1})`

You can also call `counter.most_common()`, the result will be `[(('honda', 'blue'), 2), (('nissan', 'yellow'), 1), (('bmw', 'grey'), 1)]`